# Обновление CSS с помощью LiveReload

Tags: phpstorm, gulp, scss

Использую: gulp + phpstorm + livereload в хроме.

При редактировании php-файлов изменения в браузере происходят как надо, автоматически и мгновенно.

При редактировании css страница автоматически не перезагружается, но при повторном изменении css страница автоматически перезагружается и подгружает предыдущий css файл. Т.е., получается, что автоматическое обновление страницы при редактировании css происходит со второго раза => с "опозданием" на один шаг.

В чем может быть проблема?

[**Код gulpfile.js**](http://pastebin.com/eRWKQzbe)

```
"use strict";

// ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКИЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ
var appDir = 'application';
var cssDir = newDir('/assets/styles/css');
var scssDir = newDir('/assets/styles/scss');
var gulpDir = newDir('/assets_optimized');
var pagesDir = newDir('');

// ФУНКЦИЯ ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ ПУТЬ ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНО ДИРЕКТОРИИ ПРОЕКТА
function newDir(dir) {
    return appDir + dir;
}

// ФУНКЦИЯ ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ МАСКУ ДЛЯ ФАЙЛОВ С ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫМ РАСШИРЕНИЕМ
function newSrc(dir, ext) {
    return dir + '/**/*.' + ext;
}

// PIPES
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concatCSS = require('gulp-concat-css');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var scss = require('gulp-scss');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

// DEFAULT TASK
gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'pages', 'watch']);

// WATCHERS
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(newSrc(scssDir, 'scss'), ['styles']).on('change', livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch(newSrc(pagesDir, 'php'), ['pages']).on('change', livereload.changed);
});

// STYLES
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src(newSrc(scssDir, 'scss'))
        .pipe(scss({style: 'expanded'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDir))
        .pipe(concatCSS('style.css'))
        .pipe(prefix('last 5 versions', '> 1%'))
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(gulpDir))
});

// PAGES
gulp.task('pages', function() {
    gulp.src(newSrc(pagesDir, 'php'))
});
```

Comment: попробуй использовать browsersync, вот хорошая статья по настройке http://nikovit.ru/blog/browsersync-poleznyy-instrument-dlya-verstalshchika/